# why I draw graph encounter divide by zero error?

Tags: python, networkx

I have some data like:

```
4556    5092    0.7000 
4556    4785    0.7500 
4556    5397    0.7000 
4556    5139    0.7500 
4556    5937    0.8333 
4556    6220    0.7000 
4556    5139    0.7500 
4556    6220    0.7063 
4559    4563    0.7500 
4559    4770    0.7500 
4559    4837    0.7500 
4559    5640    0.7500 
4559    4563    0.7500 
4559    4770    0.7500 
4559    4837    0.7500 
4559    5640    0.7500 
4561    4607    1.0000 
4561    4600    0.7500 
4561    4562    0.7500 
4561    5090    0.7500 
4561    5197    1.0000 
4561    5182    0.7500 
4561    5937    0.7500 
4561    6143    0.7500 
4561    5632    1.0000 
4561    5870    1.0000 
4561    6220    0.6756 
4561    6143    0.7500 
4561    6220    0.6750 
4562    4607    0.7500 
4562    5197    0.7500 
4562    5632    0.7500 
4562    5870    0.7500 
4562    6220    0.6656 
4564    4837    0.7500 
4564    4837    0.7500 
4566    5805    0.8750 
4566    5981    0.6729 
4571    4919    0.7000 
4571    6004    0.7500 
4571    6089    0.7000 
4571    6044    0.7500 
4571    6041    0.7000 
4571    5863    0.7500 
4571    6089    0.6398
```

the first two colum is node,and the third is length of edge.

my code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
filedata = file("1.txt")
for line in filedata:
    datas = line.split()
    G.add_edge(datas[0],datas[1],length=datas[2])

#nx.draw(G,with_lables=False,node_size=100)
nx.draw(G,with_lables=False,node_size=100)
plt.savefig("data.png")
#plt.show()
```

but I encouter:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg/networkx/drawing/layout.py:514: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in int_scalars
  pos[:,i]*=scale/lim
```

what's wrong with networkx?

Comment: I haven't worked with any of the libs you are using but the first thing that I can think of is that datas[2] might get casted to an int which would make it 0. Try explicitly converting it to a float.

Comment: Are you sure datas[0],datas[1] and datas[2] do contains floats? and not strings?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/networkx-discuss/DvwOq62sUnk   it's because of networkx

Comment: I believe this is down to a bug in networkx which [has been fixed](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/777). Try updating networkx.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any error on my system. But have encountered this problem often. After this warning, the networkx draws a thick black line in the center of plot and saves it. I upgraded to Networkx 1.8 and have not encountered this error so far.